# How to update custom hook value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks

I've started learning typescript and  react hooks on my new web project. I have some problem with managing initial value of my custom hook i've made. Cant step over this functionality. How should I update ***nameInput*** hook, after data is fetched from my API. For example if I pass custom string as initial value in ***useTextInput*** everything is fine, but problem is when im passing undefined first there(when data is fetched from API) and value after is downloaded, and seems like it is not updating.

My question is, how to update in AccountInput inputValue value properly by value coming from API as userAccount.firstName from getUser() method, witch depends to nameInput, witch is not updated after initial value in useTextInput.

Account.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { IApplicationState } from '../../store';
import { actionCreators, reducer, AccountStatusEnum } from '../../store/Account';
import { MDBBtn, MDBInput } from 'mdbreact';
import { AccountInput } from './child-components';
import { useTextInput } from '../../hooks';

type AccountProps = ReturnType<typeof reducer> & typeof actionCreators;

const Account: React.FC<AccountProps> = ({ getUser, resetState, userAccount, status }) => {
    const nameInput = useTextInput(userAccount.firstName);
    const [isInputInvalid, setIsInputInvalid] = useState<boolean>(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        getUser();
    }, []);

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="mt-3 container border border-light">
                    <h5 className="secondary-heading font-weight-bold pt-3 pl-5">User info</h5>
                    <div className="row">
                        <AccountInput
                            textInput={nameInput}
                            typeInput="text"
                            labelInput="Your name & surename"
                            isInputInvalid={isInputInvalid}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: IApplicationState) => state.acc;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(Account as any);
```

AccointInput.tsx

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from '../../../hooks';
import { MDBInput } from 'mdbreact';

type AccountInputProps = {
    readonly textInput: TextInput;
    readonly isInputInvalid: boolean;
    readonly typeInput: string;
    readonly labelInput: string;
};

const AccountInput = React.memo<AccountInputProps>(({ textInput, isInputInvalid, typeInput, labelInput }) => {
    const { hasValue, bindToInput } = textInput;
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="col-sm w-100 px-5">
                <MDBInput hint={textInput.value} {...bindToInput} type={typeInput} label={labelInput} />
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );

});

AccountInput.displayName = 'AccountInput';

export default AccountInput;
```

useTextInput.ts

```
import { useState, useCallback, useMemo, FormEvent } from 'react';

export type TextInputType = 'text' | 'password';

export type TextInput = {
    value: string;
    hasValue: boolean;
    clear: () => void;
    bindToInput: {
        value: string;
        type: TextInputType;
        onChange: (e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
    };
};

export const useTextInput = (initial: string = '', type: TextInputType = 'text'): TextInput => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(initial);
    const clear = useCallback((): void => setValue(''), []);
    const onChange = useCallback((e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => setValue(e.currentTarget.value), []);

    return useMemo<TextInput>(
        () => ({
            value,
            clear,
            hasValue: !!(value && value.trim()),
            bindToInput: {
                type,
                value,
                onChange,
            },
        }),
        [value, type, onChange, clear],
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure how custom hooks handle promises, but normally when you want to pass an `async` value to `useState` you do something like this:

```
const useTextInput = (initial) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initial);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(initial);
  }, [initial]);
};
```

You can use `useEffect` to update your stateful value when `initial` changes. Would this work in your case?

Comment: Yes, it is working. Well, it seems like my hook was missing from this useEffect hook. Thanks!